# Como somar os valores de colunas selecionadas de cada observação (linha) no R?

Tags: r

Tenho um banco de dados com 10.000 observações (indivíduos/linhas).

**Quero somar os valores de três variáveis (colunas) referentes a cada indivíduo (linha).**

Ex.:

```
   x1  x2   x3    x4   x5   x6
1   0   1    0    40   45   76
2   1   1    0    31   86   76
3   0   0    1    38   79   82
4   1   0    1    42   81   74

...
```

Para cada indivíduo, quero somar os valores das colunas x1, x2 e x3. Assim, a soma para cada indivíduo deveria ser (y):

```
   x1  x2   x3    x4   x5   x6   y
1   0   1    0    40   45   76   1
2   1   1    0    31   86   76   2
3   0   0    1    38   79   82   1
4   1   1    1    42   81   74   3

...
```

Já tentei a função `colSums`, `sum` e `apply`, mas estas parecem estar somando todas as colunas, pois os valores estão errado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a função `apply` restringida apenas às colunas que interessam no teu banco de dados. Por exemplo, utilizando o objeto `USArrests` como exemplo, o comando

```
USArrests[, 1:3]
```

vai exibir apenas as três primeiras colunas deste conjunto de dados. O comando

```
apply(USArrests[, 1:3], 1, sum)
```

vai somar os valores encontrados nas colunas de 1 a 3, para cada *linha* presente. O comando

```
apply(USArrests[, 1:3], 2, sum)
```

fará algo análogo, mas a soma total será calculada por coluna.

Comment: Oi Marcus, obrigada pela resposta. Entretanto, ao aplicar a função sugerida por vc, ocorreu um erro com a seleção da coluna:         banco3$ali<- apply(USArrests[, 43:57], 1, sum)
Error in `[.data.frame`(USArrests, , 43:57) : 
  colunas indefinidas selecionadas

Comment: Ao substituir USArrests pelo data.frame, deu certo! Muito obrigada mesmo, Marcus!

Answer (score 6):

Como você está somando, você também pode usar diretamente o `rowSums`, que em geral é um pouco mais rápido do que o `apply`:

```
rowSums(USArrests[,1:3])
```